# Switching the x-axis in plot without altering the math in integral

Tags: plotting

Here is the code,

```
ClearAll;
ListPlot[ParallelTable[{x, 
NIntegrate[(x - z)/(20*Sin[z]), {z, 0, 2*Pi}, MaxRecursion -> 100, 
Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, 
AccuracyGoal -> 5]}, {x, 0, 10, 1}], Joined ->
True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold], 
BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 18},
PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

and that code gives me a triangle like curve plot on positive x axis and positive y axis.
I am attempting to plot the same thing reversed on negative axis and positive y axis without changing the range in integral or function in the integral (almost mirror like reflection).  In other words, I am trying to plot the curve on negative axis by changing data plot range in list plot.  However this attempt using `DataRange`  does not work.    Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am attempting to plot the same thing reversed on negative axis and
>   positive y axis

You mean something like this?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which can be done by multiplying the `x` coordinates by `-1`

```
ClearAll;

data=ParallelTable[
        {x,NIntegrate[(x-z)/(20*Sin[z]),{z,0,2*Pi},
                       MaxRecursion->100,
                       Method->{"LocalAdaptive","SymbolicProcessing"->0},
                       AccuracyGoal->5]},{x,0,10,1}
];

dataReversed           =  data;
dataReversed[[All,1]]  = -1*dataReversed[[All,1]];

ListPlot[{data,dataReversed},Joined->True,
  AxesLabel->{"x","y"},
  LabelStyle->Directive[Black,Bold],
  BaseStyle->{FontWeight->Bold,FontSize->18},
  PlotRange->Automatic]
```

If you just want to plot the reversed data, just remove `data` from the above plot command.

Answer (score 2):

You can also post-process the output of your `ListPlot` to reflect the lines through the vertical axis:

```
lp = ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold], 
  BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 18}, PlotRange -> Automatic];

Show[lp, lp /. L_Line :> {Red, GeometricTransformation[L, ReflectionTransform[{-1, 0}]]}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Show[lp, lp /. Line[x_, y___] :> {Line[x, y], Red, Line[{-1, 1} # & /@ x, y]}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

> same picture